How to fix backward text while keeping group name?
I have some text which I want to flow into a frame. Whenever I do that, the text becomes flipped, like so:

First, I have tried flipping the text back, but that seems to affect the frame as well:

I also tried using "Reverse" on the frame, but that changed nothing.
Finally I figured out that I could ungroup the items and then re-group them. However, the group name gets lost that way. I have many such groups and I want to keep their names.
Moving the items out of the group also fixes the problem. Moving them back into the group also gets the problem back.
How could I fix this issue while keeping the group name? It has something to do with the transform matrix applied to the group, but I can't figure out how to get rid of that without changing the layout.
Download demo file (IP address is that of my server, wellisolutions.de)
My Inkscape version is 1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25, custom). The original file may have been created with Inkscape 1.2.x, before I modified it.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I can't reproduce this problem. Which version of Inkscape are you using?

@BillyKerr: good point. it's 1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25, custom). The same version as stated in the SVG file. The original file may have been created with Inkscape 1.2.x, before I modified it.

@BillyKerr: if I create that from scratch, it works fine as well. But it does not work in the given document.

OK. Here's what I found. There is a transform on the group that contains the shape, the circle and the text. You can see it in the XML Editor.  I think to fix it you will need to delete the transform, resize and reposition.

I've added an answer now. Hopefully it will help.

There's something up with the SVG. Nothing to do with Inkscape really.
I don't know how the file you shared ended up reflected like that. Anyway, it has been done using a transform on the group which contains the shape, the circle and the text. Luckily, this means it's reversible.
Select the group, open the XML editor and delete the Transform.

When you hit the delete button, everything will move into a different position, but the text and other elements will flip the proper way. Then you will have to reposition/rescale the elements.
If you then select just the circle, and the yellow shape, without selecting the text, and flip them horizontally, the text will remain unflipped.

